# Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in magento

Tags: php, magento, payumoney

I am integrating magento payumoney gateway.I am using payumoney extension available on payumoney website.But it's through this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\build\store\app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Observer.php on line 46
```

on this url

```
http://localhost/build/store/index.php/payucheckout/shared/redirect/
```

for this I follow this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31517/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getmethodinstance-on-a-non-obje

but can't understand what going on. 
my website observer code

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() != 'free') {
        return $this;
    }
```

to remove this error i have update my magento from old version to new please help to find out.

Comment: Hi, Its seems that your compiler is on or you maybe not cleared the cache after installation of the module. Disable compiler and clear all cache that check ones if module working fine or not. Also if still not work properly uninstall the module and re-install it again and clear cache this will resolve you issue.

Comment: I have already try this

Comment: have you done any customization for payments or order any where.

Comment: no I have use this marketplace extension   http://www.vnecoms.com/magento-marketplace/

Comment: Have you checked that. $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); code have order object or not make print_r($order->getData())

Comment: Hi,can you please that how did you solve it?Because i have same issue and i am also using https://www.vnecoms.com/magento-marketplace/ extension.